# What is the most reliable way to detect a mobile device using Modernizr?

Tags: javascript, modernizr, browser-feature-detection

I am developing a responsive site and I have been asked to swap any freephone numbers on our site to the landline equivalent when a user is browsing on a mobile device. What is the most reliable way to detect if a user is on a mobile device using the Modernizr library (or any other library)?

I am aware of Modernizr.touch and also Modernizr.geolocation. When the two are combined in an `if(Modernizr.touch && Modernizr.geolocation)` statement they are a good indicator of whether you are on a mobile device however an iPad will make both these attributes true. I am reluctant to test the device size because mobile devices are getting bigger and bigger!

Has anyone tackled this before?

Comment: Strictly speaking you can't tell for sure.  Even the user agent string is problematic, especially since companies introduce about a million new phone models a month. (A lot of people would call an iPad a mobile device anyway :-)

Comment: I think Modernizr tries to explicitly discourage this sort of sniffing, so they probably haven't implemented a method. However I can see that in your case you have a reason, so probably your best bet is to use `navigator.userAgent`.

Comment: Ah, I think the feature detection method might be to use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196833/android-device-phone-call-ability

Comment: @Pointy you're right, the iPad probably is a mobile device. The reason I don't want the iPad to pass the test is because you are unlikely to call from it. The user is more likely to be sat at home and they will want to see the freephone number so they can call it on their phone.

Comment: Now geolocation is true in a number of desktop browsers.  They have a link to a test suite where you can see if options are turned off/on. (http://modernizr.github.io/Modernizr/test/index.html) I checked on my Mac Mini Safari, Chrome, Firefox and Opera.  All of them had geolocation set to true.

Answer (score 3):

By using Modernizr API Method [`Modernizr.mq(str)`](http://modernizr.com/docs/#mq)

**Example:**

```
Modernizr.mq('only all and (max-width: 400px)')
```

Comment: Thanks. Like I said I am reluctant to use sizes because they can't reliably detect mobile devices but I might have to.

Comment: My phone turned on its side reports a width of 640 pixels :-)

Answer (score 2):

I use this PHP library on my website: http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/

I recommend this over a JavaScript library as it means that there is less processing to do on the mobile device and your web page code is much cleaner without conditional statements targeting more than one device.

The caveat (if you want to call it that) is that you have two versions of your website to maintain. I don't see this as a problem myself though when weighed up against maintaining webpages with conditional statements for deciding which content to display. I have a desktop folder and a mobile folder in my root directory.

I simply use the `isMobile` method and ignore most of the rest but it can be used to filter down and target specific device types if you want.

E.g. usage:

```
 // Include the mobile detection file.
 require('Mobile_Detect.php');

 // Create new mobile detect object.
 $detect = new Mobile_Detect();
 // Create new browser object
 $browser = new Browser();
 // Check if the client is using a mobile device.
 $mobile = $detect->isMobile();

 ...

 if($mobile) {
     //Load mobile site version
     require('Mobile\\index.html');
 } else {
     //Load desktop site version
     require('Desktop\\index.html');
 }
```

In your case, JavaScript may be the better solution if it is only numbers you want to change though. This answer may be more ideally suited to those looking to develop an entire site that is mobile-friendly.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the site I am developing the front end for is an .asp site. Perhaps I can talk to the developers and ask what they can do from the back end.

Comment: Well, if you wish, you could try an ASP mobile detection browser script and adapt my solution to work with ASP instead. An example script can be found here: http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/lightweight-device-detection-asp (I have no experience using this particular script though)

Comment: That library looks like just a jumble of (badly-written) patterns to apply to the user agent.

Comment: @Pointy As I said, I have no experience using the script in my previous comment. However, the PHP library I linked does something similar in that it tests for certain telling strings in the reported user-agent and can determine if it is a mobile browser from this. (Keep in mind the user-agent can be spoofed however). In my opinion, this is better than checking for the devices width though. The PHP library I linked in my answer adds very little overhead (execution time < .001 seconds) so I am happy to use it.

Comment: @Ren it's the PHP library that I was talking about :-)  You could probably make it even faster by fixing some of the goofier regular expressions.

Comment: @Pointy I see :P Well, I explained my reasons for using it above anyway :) I may look into optimizing it when I get time then so. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Was looking for a similar thing and just tried this which seemed to work fine at first glance.

http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/