# Android Market hide my Application to some tablet (like Nexus 7)

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest, google-play, uses-feature

This is my configuration of Manifest.xml, I don't understand why Nexus 7 and other tablet can't be able to download this app from market.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="10"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" android:required="false" /> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
```

In the Developer Console there is this string Layout schermo: SMALL NORMAL LARGE XLARGE so I believe that the problem is the permission. Any Suggestions?

All the Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="**********"
android:versionCode="3"
android:versionName="1.4" >

<uses-sdk 
    android:minSdkVersion="10" 
    android:targetSdkVersion="10"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" android:required="false" /> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>




<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="**************"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="InfoServizio"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="NewProfilo"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="MiaDietaActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="Percentuali"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="DatiFisiciUtente"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="ListViewFoodCategoryActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="ListViewFoodActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="FoodDescriptionActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="MiaDietaActivityWebView" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="AggiungiNuovoPiattoActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="EmailActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="ProfiloActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="InsertInitialDataActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".StoricoTabActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="PesoRiepilogoActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="GraficoRiepilogoActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="StoricoPesoActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="StoricoPietanzeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="AggiungiNuovoPiattoSecondoPassaggioActvity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="ActivityScattaFoto"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="ListViewMyFoodActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="ListViewMyFoodCategoryActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="SearchActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="HomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="GraficoOK"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="FormuleActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="CreditsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="AssociaDietologoActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo.chart.XYChartBuilder" />
    <activity android:name="org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo.chart.PieChartBuilder" />
    <activity android:name="org.achartengine.GraphicalActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".GeneratedChartDemo" />
    <activity
        android:name="AttesaDietologoActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="FacebookLikeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="TwitterGoActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="CalendarView"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I don't see any problems with that part of the Manifest.  Could you post the rest of the manifest?

Comment: Now there is all the Manifest.. I have put ****** in the name of app... I don't wont advertising :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `android:required="false"` with permissions; it is only for `uses-feature`.  Some permissions imply features.  In this case `android.permission.CALL_PHONE` implies  `android.hardware.telephony`.  The Nexus 7 doesn't have this and will be filter out.  Try this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
```

Comment: Then won't I get an error for when I try to use the telephone manager for the tablet? Is there something I can do? For example: `if(Works with telephone){//Do stuff} else{ //ignore}?`

Comment: +Ruchir Baronia - Not any straightforward way to know.  Most API's just return null if it doesn't exist on that device.  For telephony specifically I'd try this idea: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5196919/146628

Answer (score 1):

The Nexus 7 doesn't have autofocus. So if it shows in your `<uses>` tag, the app will be hidden from all devices which don't have that feature. If your app doesn't require autofocus, but just the camera, then remove that `<uses>` tag, and you should be good to go on all devices which have a camera. You might also want to change the `<uses>` tag for the camera to camera.any, as otherwise it will fail, due to lack of a back-facing camera.

Comment: This is normally true, but he specifically uses android:required="false".  Also, the "android.hardware.camera" would fail without the android:required="false" since that feature implies a back facing camera and the Nexus 7 only has a front facing.

Comment: @Grimmace, you're right on the camera vs. camera.any -- I was just updating that as your comment came through.

Comment: But when I study Android Documentation, I have understand that if I write this " android:required="false" " Market don't filters the application.. or I'm wrong?