# how to detect presence/absence of CallLog

Tags: android

Is there a preferred way to determine if an Android device has a CallLog?

An Android powered mobile phone will have one while an Android powered tablet will not.

How do I detect that?

Comment: If what you really want is to tell if you're on a phone or not, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196833/android-device-phone-call-ability

Comment: how do i mark your answer as the correct one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Device phone call ability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196833/android-device-phone-call-ability)