# Getting screen size in a class without buildcontext in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to get screen size in flutter inside a custom class which donot have build method in it. How can i get screen size without using  buildcontext class?

The following code :

```
class ShapesPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {

    BuildContext context;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final paint = Paint();

    paint.color = Colors.deepOrange;

    var center = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);

    print(height);
    print(width);

    Rect rect = Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, width, height);
    canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

gives following error :

> The following assertion was thrown during paint(): 
>   'package:flutter/src/widgets/media_query.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   689 pos 12: 'context != null': is not true.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

use

```
MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance.window);
```

you can use it to get MediaQuery without need context
it depend on instance of window to get size information

Comment: This is the only answer on this page that actually answers the original question and is correct.

Comment: An expression whose value can be 'null' must be null-checked before it can be dereferenced.
This is the error I'm getting on using this, can anyone help!

Comment: @Apoorvpandey just add an exclamation mark to it and tell the compiler that you know what you're doing like this `MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance!.window)`

Comment: Wow, very nice. I access my `height` with: `MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance.window).size.width.toInt()`. Thanks!

Comment: So you access height with width..?

Comment: It works, but once I change the orientation, for ex. from Portrait to landscape, it is not updated.

Comment: 'MediaQueryData.fromWindow' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use MediaQueryData.fromView instead.

Comment: Going by screen size doesn't work on Android as phones like pixel 5, etc. have greater than 600 short size. I haven't found a solid answer for android!

Answer (score 22):

As of May 2023, in Flutter 3.10.1 `MediaQueryData.fromWindow()` has been deprecated. Use `WidgetsBinding.instance.platformDispatcher.views.first.physicalSize.width` now. Replace width with height to get the height of the screen

Answer (score 5):

You can directly pass the screen's `width` and `height` as a parameter for the widget `ShapesPainter` if that is all what you need.

Solution Code:

```
class ShapesPainter extends CustomPainter {

  final double width;
  final double height;

  ShapesPainter({this.width,this.height});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {

    final paint = Paint();

    paint.color = Colors.deepOrange;

    var center = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);

    print(height);
    print(width);

    Rect rect = Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, width, height);
    canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
// Wherever you'll be using it
ShapesPainter(
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
)
```

Comment: You can even use `double.infinity` if you wish to.

Answer (score 2):

To complete @MohammadKhanAwan response,

WidgetsBinding.instance.platformDispatcher.views.first.physicalSize.width return the resolution (ex: 1080 / 2400) to get the same value as MediaQuery.of(context).size

you have to divided it by pixel ratio like below

```
mixin Responsive {
  final double widthScreen = WidgetsBinding
          .instance.platformDispatcher.views.first.physicalSize.width /
      WidgetsBinding.instance.platformDispatcher.views.first.devicePixelRatio;
  
final double heightScreen = WidgetsBinding
              .instance.platformDispatcher.views.first.physicalSize.height /
          WidgetsBinding.instance.platformDispatcher.views.first.devicePixelRatio;
    }
```

I wrapped the values in a mixin to easily access them from any class or Widget.

Answer (score 1):

I previously used `window` singleton to retrieve the screen width and height:

```dart
double width = (window.physicalSize.shortestSide / window.devicePixelRatio);
double height = (window.physicalSize.longestSide / window.devicePixelRatio);
```

but [it was deprecated](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/window-singleton#summary), and consequently also [MediaQueryData.fromWindow()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQueryData/MediaQueryData.fromWindow.html) (from the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68921077/19544859)) as well.

#### Solution

[`FlutterView.physicalSize`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/FlutterView/physicalSize.html) gives you

> The **dimensions of the rectangle** into which the scene rendered in this view will be drawn on the screen, in **physical** pixels.

[`FlutterView.devicePixelRatio`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/FlutterView/devicePixelRatio.html) gives you

> The number of **device pixels for each logical pixel** for the screen this view is displayed on.

By using the following snippet, you can then obtain the actual *logical* screen width and height:

```dart
FlutterView view = PlatformDispatcher.instance.views.first;

double physicalWidth = view.physicalSize.width;
double physicalHeight = view.physicalSize.height;

double devicePixelRatio = view.devicePixelRatio;

double screenWidth = physicalWidth / devicePixelRatio;
double screenHeight = physicalHeight / devicePixelRatio;
```

Answer (score -5):

In the following way, you can get the device screen size without declaring them in the build method.

```
  void paint(BuildContext context)
{
  double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
  double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
}
```

And you can access them inside other file build methods after importing this method.

```
paint(context)
```