# How can I get the screen size in Flutter without BuildContext?

Tags: flutter, dart

Firstly, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57755174/getting-screen-size-in-a-class-without-buildcontext-in-flutter), though similiar in Question, is not what I need as the Answer does not help me in my case.

I have my AppConfig decide the fontsize, based on device, so that very big devices, such as Tablets, get bigger Texts (by a bit). My config gets called before any Views, so I have no BuildContext while this is running. So how can I do this?

```dart
class AppConfig {
  static AppConfig _instance;

  static AppConfig instance() {
    if (_instance == null) {
      _instance = AppConfig();
    }
    return _instance;
  }

// config stuff for colours and themes

double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

if (width > 500) { //arbitrary number I haven't decided yet
    initWithBigFonts();
} else {
    initWithSmallFonts();
}
```

Comment: what about `WidgetsBinding.instance.window`?

Comment: @pskink that looks like what i'd need but - how would i use it here?

Comment: check [Window](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Window-class.html) class properties

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For future reference the full solution to this:

By adding

```dart
Size size = WidgetsBinding.instance.window.physicalSize;
double width = size.width;
double height = size.height;
```

You can, from anywhere and without BuildContext, get the Size from the device screen.

Answer (score 5):

in this case, you should think about the devicePixelRatio;

```
Size size = WidgetsBinding.instance.window.physicalSize;
double ratio = WidgetsBinding.instance.window.devicePixelRatio;
double width = size.width / ratio;
```

Answer (score 4):

the "window" singleton has been deprecated as of v3.7.0-32.0.pre because "window" assumed that the app consists of a single view which is not the case anymore. You can use one of the following two options.

- `PlatformDispatcher.instance.views.first.physicalSize.` or,
- `PlatformDispatcher.instance.implicitView?.physicalSize` (nullable)

divide the physicalSize by the devicePixelRatio (PlatformDispatcher.instance.views.first.devicePixelRatio) to get the view size.

For more info, https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/window-singleton

Answer (score 1):

Size size = MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance.window).size;

Answer (score 1):

#### Update

`window` is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Instead use `PlatformDispatcher`.

```dart
final view = WidgetsBinding.instance.platformDispatcher.views.first;
final size = view.physicalSize;
final pixelRatio = view.devicePixelRatio;

// Size in physical pixels:
final width = size.width;
final height = size.height;

// Size in logical pixels:
final width = size.width / pixelRatio;
final height = size.height / pixelRatio;
```