# How to Lock Mobile Phone Screen Orientation In Flutter? (Not in Tabs/ iPads)

Tags: flutter, dart, layout, flutter-layout, screen-orientation

I have developed an app using flutter. Now I want to lock it's screen orientation only in mobile phones. Because I cannot provide the functionalities for mobile landscape mode as there is not an enough scape for it. So, how can I do it? The important thing is I don't want to lock the screen orientation for tabs/ iPads.

Comment: This question should give you all you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49484549/can-we-check-the-device-to-be-smartphone-or-tablet-in-flutter

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart'; 
       
       //When you load the Widget, do something like this:
       
       @override
       void initState(){
         super.initState();
        if(getDeviceType == ‘phone’){    
             SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
                DeviceOrientation. portraitUp,
             ]);    
        }    
        else{
            SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([    
                DeviceOrientation. portraitUp,
                DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
                DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
          ]);
        }
       }
       
       
       String getDeviceType() {
           final data = MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance.window);
           return data.size.shortestSide < 600 ? 'phone' :'tablet';
         }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jignesh You solved my question. It's working fine.

Comment: @ChanakaNiroshan - If above answer is correct then accept it. It will help other to find right solution.

Comment: @Sachin - Yes. That answer is correct and I have thank him for the answer. Is there any other thing to do to accept correct answers?

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() async {

  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

use it in `main.dart` like this. Change DeviceOrientation as you want. Add more DeviceOrientation or remove. Whatever you want