# How to make a responsive widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, responsive-design, responsive

I want to make a responsive widget. I want it to change to another style of screen when using a different device.

I've read multiple questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49484549/16124033), but still can't find an answer. The answer is pretty much checking if the device is mobile, tablet or desktop by screen width. If I do this, when I rotate the mobile device, it shows the tablet style screen even though I'm using a mobile device.

However, I see an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73189199/16124033) that uses the package, not the way. However, I get the following error when using the package:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
LateInitializationError: Field 'deviceType' has not been initialized.
The relevant error-causing widget was
LayoutBuilder
lib/…/responsive.dart:18
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sizer/sizer.dart';

class Responsive extends StatelessWidget {
  const Responsive({required this.mobile, required this.tablet, required this.desktop, super.key});

  final Widget mobile;
  final Widget tablet;
  final Widget desktop;

  static bool isMobile(BuildContext context) => MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 600.0 && SizerUtil.deviceType == DeviceType.mobile;

  static bool isTablet(BuildContext context) => MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 1100.0 && MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= 600.0 && SizerUtil.deviceType == DeviceType.tablet;

  static bool isDesktop(BuildContext context) => MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= 1100.0 && SizerUtil.deviceType != DeviceType.mobile && SizerUtil.deviceType == DeviceType.tablet;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) => constraints.maxWidth >= 1100.0 && SizerUtil.deviceType != DeviceType.mobile && SizerUtil.deviceType != DeviceType.tablet
            ? desktop
            : constraints.maxWidth < 1100.0 && constraints.maxWidth >= 600.0 && SizerUtil.deviceType == DeviceType.tablet
                ? tablet
                : mobile,
      );
}
```

Feel free to leave a comment if you need more information.

How to make a responsive widget? I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

try to Do It like package official example.
https://github.com/TechnoUrmish/Sizer/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart

```
Sizer(
      builder: (context, orientation, deviceType) {
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'Sizer',
          theme: ThemeData.light(),
          home: HomeScreen() ,
        );
      },
    );
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! Although this answer solved my error, my main question is how to make responsive widget

Comment: It is very easy try to write your code for three devices (Mobile/Tab/Desktop), with package like Sizer, you can check where your code is running (mobile, tab or desktop). you just need to adjust the your widget size (width/height) accordingly,

Apart from Package you can use MediaQuery/ AspectRatio /LayoutBuilder to make your widget responsive so they look best on given device.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Sizer` widget on top of MaterialApp to initialize it. Like the doc example,

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Sizer(//this
      builder: (context, orientation, deviceType) {
        return MaterialApp(
```

I will follow

```dart
class Responsive extends StatelessWidget {
  const Responsive(
      {required this.mobile,
      required this.tablet,
      required this.desktop,
      super.key});

  final Widget mobile;
  final Widget tablet;
  final Widget desktop;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
      LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
        if (constraints.maxWidth > 600)
          return mobile;
        /// else if (constraints.maxWidth < 1100.0) return tablet; this can be
        else if (constraints.maxWidth >= 600.0 && constraints.maxWidth < 1100.0)
          return tablet;

        return desktop;
      });
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! Although this answer solved my error, my main question is how to make responsive widget

Comment: Actually it depends on the widget. Like sometime we will use wrap widget instead of Row. and when the UI is different, i may use different widget for this. For me layoutBuilder was enough. You can follow [adaptive-responsive](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/adaptive-responsive)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any third party library then you can use `LayoutBuilder`.
or you can use `Sizer` library.

[Link](https://pub.dev/packages/sizer)

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! I'm using that package and getting an error. The error is included in the question

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `SizerUtil.deviceType` you must wrap the parent widget of your app with the `Sizer` widget. To make your app responsive, you can use the `w`, `h`, and `sp` extensions functions provided with the sizer package. These functions allow you creation widget and fonts in proportion to the screen size. For example:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Sizer(
      builder: (context, orientation, deviceType) => MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (SizerUtil.deviceType == DeviceType.tablet) {
      return Container(width: 100.w, height: 50.h, color: Colors.red);
    } else {
      return Container(width: 60.w, height: 40.h, color: Colors.red);
    }
  }
}
```

In the above, if the device is a tablet, the Container takes up 100% (`100.w`) of the widget and 50% (`50.h`) of the height. Else, the Container is sized differently.

The `.sp` extension works similarly except that it's for fonts.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! Your answer solved my error, however, if I do this, when I rotate the mobile device, it shows the tablet style screen even though I'm using a mobile device.

Comment: Sizer uses the device width to determine whether the device tablet or mobile.Use `Device.orientation` to determine the device orientation in combination with `SizerUtil.deviceType` to render your widgets.

Comment: Hi, how to use `Device.orientation`? Can you update your answer and show how to use it?