# How can I know the android tablet device can use telephony or not?

Tags: android, tablet, telephony

When the user taps the phone number field, my ANDROID app makes a call.
However, on many tablet devices, users cannot use telephone.

So I need to change the manifest like this.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

In fact, this feature is just only additional function and not required.
Therefore, I want users to use the app on their tablet devices.
And I shall avoid making phone calls on the tablet device to avoid errors.

How can I know if this device can make phone calls?

For your information, I make calls on webview like this in my APP. It works well on the phone devices.

```
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            view.reload();
            return true;
        }
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be a duplicate and very well answered here, including the case where the user has installed an app that can make phone calls regardless of the ability of the device itself (e.g. Skype):
[Android Device phone call ability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196833/android-device-phone-call-ability)